# Fresh install of IIS Express 10 get the same error when trying to run iisexpress /trace:i

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-express

I cd into the c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express and run iisexpress /trace:i ge the following
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error)

I have tried re installing iis express, creating the iisexpress folder structure in the [currentuser] documents folder.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the error we expected when IIS Express cannot resolve a default config file. You can learn more from `iisexpress /?` and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Comment: Have you tried running iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled? and you can also check if the time zone of your system is correct.

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies. The time zone is correct, and using the trace results in the same error. I have tried setting the config switch to the exact location of a config and still the same error. In fact all commands apart from "iisexpress /? result in the same message. Could it be that IIS Express requires certain permissions to access the applicationhost.config file?

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.